# Projecting specified fields within an array in MongoDB (missing ] error?)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, field, projection

In MongoDB, I understand that to project only specified fields in a collection, I would execute:

```
db.collection.find({}, {"field1": 1, "field2": 1})
```

But what would I do if I wanted to only project specified fields within an array in a collection? The only way I can think would be this:

```
db.collection.find({field1: [arrayfield1: 1, arrayfield2: 1, arrayfield3: 1]})
```

But I get "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list (shell):1".
I've tried this as well:

```
db.collection.find({field1: [arrayfield1: 1], [arrayfield2: 1], [arrayfield3: 1]})
```

And get the same error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Because I can't figure it out. Or if I'm on the completely wrong track?

(I'm aware that the error says "element list," and I believe it should be a field list or something to that extent, so I suspect this is not the correct way to go about what I'm trying to do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer was dot notation. This did the trick:

```
db.colletion.find({}, {  "array.arrayfield1" : 1, "array.arrayfield2" : 1, "array.arrayfield3" : 1 })
```

Comment: your right that does work   db.fred.find({},{"zipcode":1,"students.name":1,"students.age":1})